# Showing "Forbidden" message when creating meetings MS Teams

Tags: api, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-api-management

I am trying to integrate ms teams API to my project. I have created an app in the Azure portal.I have added permissions User.ReadWriteAll and Meetings.ReadWriteAll.I can create a user through API but I am not able to create a meeting. Is there anything else I need to do for creating a meeting using API.

**UPDATE**
I gave delegated permission for creating the meeting,but unable to create the meeting.
**Error Message**

```
{code:"Forbidden",message:"Forbidden",innerError:{"request-id":"e1abb815-09d3-4b78-5063-39b0236c0968","Date":"2020-06-09T04:14:39"}}
```

**Permissions**
[Screenshot of permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH8Vf.png)

Comment: Could you please check your permission is granted?

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.).This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT I have granted admin consent for API permissions

Comment: Please add more details about the error message while creating a meeting.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether there is user interaction.

If you are get access on behalf of a user[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0),follow this way `app-user`,just add delegated permission `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite`.[please check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

[image]

If you get access without a user[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0),follow this way `app-only`,just add application permission `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All`.(Please note that this  method can only use `beta` version  [https://graph.microsot.com/beta](http://%20https://graph.microsot.com/beta)).[please check beta version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions)
[image]

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: I have added required permissions and given as application permission and I'm using the beta version.

Comment: @AswinSNath   The beta version is currently used for testing.

Comment: @AswinSNath  I hope my answer is helpful to you.

Comment: I reimplemented api integration with delegate permission in my project.Still this error is shown

Comment: @AswinSNath  Please add more details about the error message and I will test it.

Comment: {code:"Forbidden",message:"Forbidden",innerError:{"request-id":"e1abb815-09d3-4b78-5063-39b0236c0968","Date":"2020-06-09T04:14:39"}}

Comment: I need you to provide two screenshots: parse your access token according to https://jwt.io/ and provide screenshots and API permissions screenshots of the application.

Comment: I parsed the access token in jwt.io and found to have permission for readwrite meetings.I added screenshot in the question

Comment: @AswinSNath If you are using delegated permissions, please grant administrator consent for "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite".

Comment: I gave administartor consent for the OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite Permission.But still the issue is not resolved

Comment: I can use https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer (this requires you to log in) to successfully create and create meeting, maybe you can try it. I will update the screenshot in the answer.

Comment: Are you using a work or school account, because this does not support personal Microsoft accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You should check what kind of permissions are added for your app. To be able to create a meeting, only **delegated** permission `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite` is supported - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

If you have added an application permission, then the request for creating meetings won't work.

Update:

In the beta version of the MS Graph API, there is an `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All` application permission which doesn't seem to be implemented yet. There is a note on the documentation page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions) that supports this.

> Creating an online meeting with an application token will be supported
>   in the near future.

Comment: Application permission will work if you are using the beta version of the graph api.I can create user using application permission

Comment: Check the following address: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions - there is currently a note regarding the creation of meetings using the beta version of the API - Creating an online meeting with an application token will be supported in the near future. 

The creation of meetings should be possible with application permissions in the beta version of the API but it seems that that is currently not the case. 

The only alternative right now seems to be Delegated permissions.

Comment: I reimplemented the integration with delegated permission but it still shows same error